# material check box not checked even model value is true

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a mat-table with some data and check boxes, which should be checked when `model.select` property is true, but when I am using `[(ngModel)]="element.select"` all the checkboxes are getting checked. below is the code,

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
   {{element.select}}
   <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.select" formControlName="select" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

Please let me know whats wrong in this code ?

I have tried property binding `[checked]="model.select"` as well. Its not working with this also.

checkbox should be checked when `element.select` has true.

Comment: show us the `element` object

Comment: please share your full code

Comment: Please check the element object below,
{
  "compId": "DataGenerator_514209",
  "select": false,
  "excludeFields": [
    "SepalLength",
    "SepalWidth",
    "PetalLength",
    "PetalWidth",
    "Species",
    "IndexedSpecies",
    "deci",
    "booleandata",
    "datedata",
    "ipdata",
    "geodata",
    "Species1",
    "DiscretePlaceHolder",
    "item"
  ]
}

Comment: add full code(html and ts)

Comment: I can not add full code due some policy in my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of  reactive forms ( `formControlName`) and template driven forms (`ngModel`) and that maybe is causing some problems.

I would try to get rid of that `formControlName` and It should work as you want.

**Here is an example without the formControlName:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-checkboxtable-55568107
 (It's based on the example of the material itself)

As you can see in this example the `[(ngModel)]` works as expected having and if you add the `formControlName` it works a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Add   [`[checked]`](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#-code-check-code-) attribute to the `ckeckbox` as  `[checked]="element.select"` :

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.select"  [checked]="element.select" formControlName="select" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to check checkbox as per the condition of `element.select` then you need to put `element.select` for your property binding as `[checked]=element.select` instead of `model.select`. so, try like this:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{element.select}}
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.select" [checked]="element.select" formControlName="select" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
</td>
```